# Array value is replaced when second one stores in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session

I am storing session values into array getting from URL and try to display it (getting size of product in a shopping cart).
But first value is replaced by second one.

My code:

```
if(isset($_POST['radio'])){
    $_SESSION['sz']=$_POST['radio'];
    $si=$_SESSION['sz'];
}

<a href="product_detail.php?pdt_id='.$pdid.'&add=' .$pdid .'&size='.$si.'" 
 class="cartBtn" onclick="return fun1()">Add to cart</a>';

?>
```

Display page:

```
$rt=$_GET['size'];
$_SESSION['wer']=$rt;
$array = $_SESSION['wer'];  //Assigns session var to $array
//print_r($array);  
echo $array[$x];
}
```

Comment: heh... what is "$x" ? oO

Comment: Sorry line is missing...

Comment: for( $x = 0, $max = count($array); $x < $max; ++$x ) {
    print_r($array[$x]);
}

Comment: There're some much mistakes in your `<a`. You don't store it nore echo it so I've no idea what is it. And you don't use dots proprely. replace your <a> with `<a href= "product_detail.php?pdt_id=$pdid&add=$pdid&size=$si" class="cartBtn" onclick="return fun1()">Add to cart</a>;`

Comment: Because the way you wrote it your url would look like `product_detail.php?pdt_id='.$pdid.'&add=' .$pdid` and it doesn't look like a URL at all...

Comment: Is this the complete code? And what is $array ? Is it the variable for the array then why are you assigning it a new value. Push the value to it like this ```$array[]=$_SESSION['wer']``` or use ```array_push()```

Comment: YES it is inside PHP TAG ...here am not able to paste whole code...am getting value from url in view page...and even its displayin..is there any problem to the way am assign the array....please help me

Comment: @khan..this is not complete code...i tried your code...not working....when am purchasing a product am getting its size..next time with a new product old value was replaced...

Comment: You need to move the `?>` to after the `}` before the `<a`

Comment: if he moves the ?> then where will the url get variables ($si, ..) come from ?

Answer (score 1):

About **First part** mistakes :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['radio'])){
        $_SESSION['sz']=$_POST['radio'];
        $si=$_SESSION['sz'];
    }
    <a href="product_detail.php?pdt_id='.$pdid.'&add=' .$pdid .'&size='.$si.'"      class="cartBtn" onclick="return fun1()">Add to cart</a>';
?>
```

1. Your a tag is completely wrong as @Hearner said. It should be out of the php tag or inside with an "echo" like this :

   ```
   echo "<a href='product_detail.php?pdt_id=".$pdid."&add=".$pdid."&size=".$si."' class='cartBtn' onclick='return fun1()'>Add to cart</a>";
   ```
2. You cannot access your $si variable out of your if statement. As written here over, if your $si isn't declared before (since you said that it was not your complete code...) then $si (in the link href) does not exist. You should therefore declare it before your if statement OR place your link (a tag) inside your if statement too!
3. What if your "$_POST['radio']" is NOT set ?? what happens? code missing... !! is $si declared anyway?

About **Second part** :

```
<?php
    for( $x = 0, $max = count($array); $x < $max; ++$x ) {
        $rt=$_GET['size'];
        $_SESSION['wer']=$rt;
        $array = $_SESSION['wer'];
        echo $array[$x];
    }
?>
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do here... need more code/information... cannot help more without your whole code...

EDIT :

Here is a very simple example to show you how to keep your get vars into a session array.

page one (pageOne.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!(isset($_SESSION['myTest']))){
        $_SESSION['myTest'] = "AWESOME";
        $_SESSION['varToKeep'] = [];
    }else{
        echo "A session is already started. This is : ".$_SESSION['myTest']."<br/>";
        if(count($_SESSION['varToKeep']>0)){
            echo "There are ".count($_SESSION['varToKeep'])." vars in the array!<br/>";
            for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['varToKeep']);$i++){
                echo "Item ".$i." : ".$_SESSION['varToKeep'][$i]."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br/>Click below to add a value in array<br/>";
    $random = rand(1,100);
    echo "<a href='pageTwo.php?mygetvar=STACKTEST".$random."'>Click here</a>";

?>
```

page two (pageTwo.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "myTest value is : ".$_SESSION['myTest']."<br/><br/>";

    $value = $_GET['mygetvar'];
    $_SESSION['varToKeep'][] = $value;
    echo "<a href='pageOne.php'>CLICK HERE TO RETURN ON PAGE ONE!</a>";
?>
```

Comment: All my array values are replaced by last value:result is like this            Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 )

Comment: You have opening/closing php tags everywhere... your code is a mess... You should really be careful about syntax and keep your code readable... I commented your productdetailpage here http://pastebin.com/RD1zZ5Kg and tried to "order" your cart file but didnt really check the logic here http://pastebin.com/YtpFSvWR Try to "isolate" the problem. Get what's wrong. And try to fix just the problem without the rest of the code... Then, check in your code what are the differences and check them one by one...

Comment: hi juloOsS..Thank you very much for your help...i will look into it and get you back.

Comment: Exact problem is, In product detail page when radio button clicked the value is stored in a session variable.and in cart fun page   stored like this.               $sif=$_SESSION['sz'];
  $sdp[]=$sif; print_r($sdp)  ;page try to store it in an array.first item no problem...when try to add second item the whole value replaced by last value..like so when adding more items...problem is only for size...

Comment: you lose your page variables if you switch page... try using session array instead of session variable like $_SESSION['sz'][] instead of var[] ;

Comment: Itry so                                                                                  $sif=$_SESSION['sz'][];
  $sdp[]=$sif; my page is taking too much of time to load.

Comment: no... put your size value into the next element of array, like this : $_SESSION['sz'][] = $value; Like this the last $_session['sz'] element will be the last size you got...

Comment: If you are logged, when you change page, you keep your $_SESSION vars. If you need to keep something then use the $session var. If not, use "simple" vars on your page. Is it clear for you now?

Comment: I understand .....but my values are getting replaced in array..i dont know how to correct it...is there any problem you can see on mu code...if so please correct me ..please...

Comment: Thank you Julo0sS...Finally i did it with your help...I had a doubt that how can i place these sizes to corresponding products.product displaying inside  a while loop and size displaying inside a for loop.